# Buttons Generating other Buttons

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

So, i'm asking cause i searched and didn't found nothing about this, i don't know if i'm only searching it wrong.

I'm building a POS (Point of Sale) for my final School work but instead off adding the buttons manually i wanted to make an interface for the admn where he could add the buttons to the main project (ex. I want to add the button for Meat, Fish, etc.)
It's much likely to be easy to do it, my other doubt becomes with, if the button is generated how it will be called so i can use it later on?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you experience trouble? I can already tell you: Yes, you can do that. We won't write all the code for you though, but we will be glad to help you in the process when you attempted something yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the NetBeans form designer you can see what code must be created.

Then instead of jButton1, jButton2 use `List<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<>();`

In the `initComponents` (or after its call) create the buttons dynamically, using some list with button data: caption Meat / Fish / ... and so on. These data could come from a file you generated, so they are persist even if quitting the application.

A file can be read as:

```
Path path = Paths.get("buttons.txt");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
for (String line : lines) {
    String[] words = line.split(";\\s*");
    if (words.length > 2 && words[0].equals("button")) {
        JButton button = new JButton(word[1]);
        button.addActionListener(this); ...
        ... add(button);
        buttons.add(button);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't generate new buttons. The best way is to hide the buttons you've created by calling button.setVisibility(View.Gone). So just create buttons and call setVisibility(View.Gone) in onCreate. And where needed make them visible by calling button.setVisibility(View.visible).